# What is the difference between px, em and ex?

Tags: css

What is the difference between `px`, `em` and `ex`? And when you define font-size in CSS, do you use `px`, `pt` or `em`?

Comment: Related and possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932773/should-i-use-em-or-px, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348978/are-there-any-practical-reasons-to-use-em-instead-of-pt-font-size-units, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132685/font-size-in-css-or-em, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609517/why-em-instead-of-px.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. Pixels (`px`) are browser dependent. It is the absolute size that you would see on your screen.
2. `Em` are sort of like percentages. `Em`s is referring to the base text size. The value of `1 em` means the same thing as a value of `100 percent`. But you can also say it in the opposite way: A percentage value is just an `em` multiplied by 100.
3. Points(`pt`) are what you would want to use in print media.

Comment: Don't you mean that pixels are *screen*-dependent? They look the same on whatever browser you use, but change depending *solely* on the screen/display settings.

Comment: the parallel to percentages is very misleading, because the percentage is not inheritly linked to the font size

Comment: @JanusTroelsen — When dealing with font sizes it is.

Comment: This answer ignores a third of the question: `ex` (surely, it's strongly related to the `em` and might not make too much sense when talking about *font sizes*, but that's no reason just to ignore it).

Comment: @Jasper, I agree I looked at this answer in hope just to find he difference between `em` and `ex`

Comment: `em` is not percent. `font-size:1em` may have the same effect as `font-size:100%`, but `1em` and `100%` have different effects elsewhere and mean fundamentally different things. An `em` is the current [font size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11073839/4200548). `font-size:1em` only has the same effect as `font-size:100%` because percents in that context are interpreted as percents of `1em`. Thus, the answer is simply describing how the `font-size` property is interpreted when it has a percent value.

Answer (score 47):

> **em** : the `font-size` of the relevant font
>   **ex** : the `x-height` of the relevant font
>   **px** : pixels, relative to the viewing device

Comment: What is the `x-height`? Is it the height of 'x' character?

Comment: @anton_rh - exactly right, x-height is the distance from the baseline to the median. Which is also the height of the lowercase x. Visual: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-height#/media/File:Typography_Line_Terms.svg

Answer (score 23):

CSS Length Units:

- **Absolute**:  Inches(**in**), centimeter(**cm**), milimeter (**mm**), points (**pt**), picas (**pc**)

**Points** are standard typographical measurements that have been used by printers and typesetters for decades and by word-processing programs for many years. Traditionally, there are 72 points to an inch (points were defined before widespread use of the metric system). Therefore, the capital letters of text set to 12 points should be one-sixth of an inch tall. For example, p {font-size: 18pt;} is equivalent to p {font-size: 0.25in;}.

**Picas** are another typographical term. A pica is equivalent to 12 points, which means there are 6 picas to an inch. As just shown, the capital letters of text set to 1 pica should be one-sixth of an inch tall. For example, p {font-size: 1.5pc;} would set text to the same size as the example declarations found in the definition of points.

These units are really useful only if the browser knows all the details of the monitor on which your page is displayed, the printer you're using, or whatever other user agent might apply. On a web browser, display is affected by the size of the monitor and the resolution to which the monitor is setand there isn't much that you, as the author, can do about these factors. **absolute units are much more useful in defining style sheets for printed documents**, where measuring things in terms of inches, points, and picas is common. As you've seen, attempting to use absolute measurements in web design is perilous at best.

- **Relative**: **em** (em-height), **ex** (x-height), **px**. The first two stand for  and "x-height," which are common typographical measurements; however, in CSS, they have meanings you might not expect if you are familiar with typography.

**em**: one "em" is defined to be the value of **font-size** for a given font. If the font-size of an element is 14 pixels, then for that element, 1em is equal to 14 pixels.

**ex**: refers to the **height of a lowercase x** in the font being used. Therefore, if you have two paragraphs in which the text is 24 points in size, but each paragraph uses a different font, then the value of ex could be different for each paragraph. This is because different fonts have different heights for x

**px**: tiny boxes of color in a monitor are pixels. In general, if you declare something like *font-size: 18px*, a web browser will almost certainly use actual pixels on your monitor after all, they're already there but with other display devices, like printers, the user agent will have to **rescale pixel lengths to something more sensible**. In other words, the printing code has to figure out how many dots there are in a pixel, and to do so, it may use the 96ppi reference pixel.

**Conclusion**

Because of this potential for rescaling, pixels are defined as a relative unit of measurement, even though, in web design, they behave much like absolute units.

[Rrefrence: css the definite guid by eric meyer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CVDORV2)

Answer (score 11):

> what is the difference px,em and ex?

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units describes those and the other length units available in CSS

> And when you define font-size in css, do i use px,pt or em?

As a rule of thumb, use percentages on screen and pt for print.

Comment: I would argue that using em or ex is better than percentages for alignment that is strongly dependent on text, since those values correspond to font sizes.

Comment: @dbmikus — `ex` is a bit weird, most people don't want to express font sizes in those term. `1em` is exactly `100%` so the correlation is exactly the same. Some older browsers (and note when the answer was written) were buggy when it came to font sizes in em units, so percentages were measurably superior. These days that doesn't matter as much.