# Which unit of measurement is best for webpage layouts, px, percentages, or ems? 

Tags: css, layout, usability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference px,em and ex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385829/what-is-the-difference-px-em-and-ex)

I have a question for all the coding geniuses on StackOverflow.
I am a newbie, and I am about to start building my third website. Being that I had some problems with the layouts of my first two websites, I am asking this question before I start on my third:

> What measurement is it best to use for
>   the css elements? Percents,EM's or Px?

Which form of measurement will ensure that I have a site that will not get distorted on different browser sizes/resolutions? Is there anything else that I have to be careful of when building my site so that it will not get distorted when a user zooms, or looks at the site from a different browser size/ resolution? (as was he case on my other sites)

Thanks for your time, guys. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for posting this question. Eagerly waiting for someone to answer :)

Comment: Do you honestly think that there's only a single answer that would work for all websites? If that was the case, do you not think the other measures would have been deprecated?

Comment: check out this [w3c tip on units](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html)

Answer (score 8):

**Whichever is easier for you to work with.**

Modern browsers (i.e. everything in use today except for IE6 and IE7) have a concept of "CSS pixels" which is different from "actual pixels," so e.g. zooming changes the size of a ["CSS pixel."](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html) Fonts will scale just fine; if you say the font is 14px, it will start out that way, but if the user zooms it'll get bigger. Thus, if it's easy for you to measure in pixels, for example to size page elements relative to an image of a given pixel size, you should do pixels.

Sometimes you want to size things relative to text, though. If the width of an em-dash is a useful measurement, somewhat representing the "longest possible character," go ahead and use ems.

And finally, if you're trying for a fluid layout, percentages can be great: a gradient that starts fading 50% across the page is often what you want, as opposed to one that starts fading after some fit number of pixels. Even if you're not fluid, and the width of your container is fixed to e.g. 900px, it's still often useful to say "this goes at the 50% mark" or "I have one thing at the 33% mark and one at the 66% mark." That's much easier to work with than figuring out what the corresponding pixel offset is every time, and makes your intent clearer to anyone reading your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You say that if px is easy for me to use, I should. I would appreciate if you get the chance to look at a page of my website, http://newstylesignsusa.com/sign_types.html. Check using firefox, (because IE does not have this problem.) Zoom in/ out, and the page gets distorted. I started ot coding this page with px,because it was the easiest for me, and it caused this distortion problem. I tried swiching to percents / ems, and the problem still remained. Any idea why? Thanks again for your time!

Comment: @suavedesign: What's distorted about it? Zooming in and out works great in my Firefox.

Comment: @Domenic Try zooming in and out when you have checked the "Zoom Text Only" option in Firefox.  The layout rapidly deteriorates as the floats get knocked out of alignment by the changing size of the content.

Comment: Oh! Well, the problem there is that you're using `float` for something other than what it was intended for, namely, floating images inside large blocks of text. Avoid `float` like the plague, and you should have no problems. Besides, nobody turns on "Zoom Text Only" anyway...

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: it depends.

Longer answer:

There is a place for all three units, frequently in the same design.  There is no "best" unit; they serve different purposes.

Pixel units generally offer the most precise control over the size of the elements in the user interface, but also restrict that size such that it does not change with regard to the other elements of the page design.  The size of pixels themselves may change.  For example, a Retina display packs more pixels into the same physical space as a non-Retina display, so images which were designed for traditional displays get scaled up.  Similarly, traditional desktop web browsers may adjust the size of pixel in response to the user zooming the size of a page.  In these cases however, the pixels change sizes throughout the entire document, and retain the same proportions with regard to one another, so you can use px values and expect them to work sanely in most conditions.

EM units vary according to the size of the text.  They're most commonly used for setting the size of text, and for line heights; but there have been some interesting things done with "elastic" layouts such as the [elastic lawn zen garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/063/063.css&page=0) (turn off page zoom for this site; switch to text-only zoom and change the size a few times).

Percentages vary according to the size of the containing element, expanding and contracting depending on how much room is available to them.

And, really, it's very common to see web designs that use all of these.  For example, suppose you have a site with two columns.  The main column must expand and contract with the browser width, but the secondary column needs to stay the same width.  The main column might have a width of 100%, but also a margin set in pixels for the secondary column to float in.  And the text and line height might be set in ems.

So, the real answer is: they all have their uses.  Keep practicing, and pretty soon you'll figure out how it all fits together.

EDIT: In the example above, I should have said "a width of auto" -- meaning take up all available space after margins, padding, and borders are accounted for.  Sorry, I tend to think of that as a percentage even though it's actually a keyword.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond to my question. You say that px offers the most control over the element sze but restricts the size, so that it can't change. Shouldn't this always cause poblems then? Because every user has a different size browser, so something that looks god in my browser can't possibly look good in everybody elses's browsers if the elements don't change size according to the browser size. Isn't that correct? Thanks.

Comment: @suavedesign You cannot design a page that looks good in *every* circumstance. There are simply too many possible combinations of screen size, window size, browser software, and visual acuity. No matter how good you are, and no matter how hard you try, eventually someone will look at your page using some combination that you didn't anticipate, and it will break. Fact of life as a web designer. So, the way to do it is collect stats on your users' browsers/screens/etc, and design to work well with the *majority* of them. With some care, you can hit 95-99% of them. The others are just SOL.

Comment: -1 the statement "a pixel is a pixel" is wrong. the browser can and often does change the size of the pixel, for example zoom.

Comment: It was true in 2011, when this answer was initially written.  In the succeeding five years, conditions have changed, and I will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

from accessability point of view need to use EM's.  You need you layout to adapt to very different fonts sizes so if allmeasurements are in EM's everything will scale as accessability tools increase font size

Comment: This isn't really true any more. No -1, since it used to be at one time, but anyone designing for the modern web shouldn't hold on to old knowledge like this.

Answer (score 0):

When creating liquid layouts, it makes sense to use percentages for the widths of your blocks, so they shrink and grow with browser size changes.

For heights, pts have a specific spatial value, and em are related to your current point size. This is useful because things specified in those units will be roughly the same size on everyone's display (unless they have different zoom factors applied). em are also useful when working with a dimension driven by an amount of text.

Browsers will also scale values specified in pixels, so they are not any more a "trap", but they are rarely the "natural" choice for layouts, unless working with raster images.

As Will and Domenic say: use all three, when appropriate. As you get more experience, you'll get a better feel for when to use which.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to design a fixed layout website then use px or em.
If you want to design a fluid layout website then use percentages.

Percentage is always relative so page content with dimensions in percentage will automatically resize on window resize and on different screen resolutions.

px and em are one and the same thing. Same in their nature. They define the absoluteness of the dimensions. Btw for the difference, `1em=current font size`. So if your `html` or `body` has css `font-size:19px;` then `1em=19px.`

Comment: thanks for answering this questions. If percentages is the only measurement that scales according to he screen size, why would I want to use px then? thanks.

Comment: Because, scalable websites are more prone to strange display and rendering in diff browsers, diff resolutions etc. So mostly people use fixed layout, that had to be shown properly on most of the browsers and resolutions. For example, this page that you are viewing. Try resizing your screen resolution, the size of this content container will always be the same. Here, this container is of fixed width i.e, 705 px. BUt it is aligned in the middle using %. So experienced developers know where to use what. using px is the easiest and % is most beneficial but requires a lot of experience.