# CSS Font Size Specifics

Tags: html, css, rendering, font-size

I have a couple of specific questions about font size:

1. Is pt (I.E. 12pt) standardized?  I think I read somewhere that pt = 1/72 of an inch.  However, the size of 24pt font in photoshop is significantly different from size 24pt font in css.
2. What exactly does font-size determine? Is it a sort of unstandardized arbitrary description about letter size or does it actually refer to the specific height or width attribute of letters?

Thanks Stack!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

font-size is the baseline height of the font (the height of a capital H character) plus a little room above it (the ascender) and larger amount of room below it (the descender).

For a particular font at a particular font-size, the baseline height will always be the same size. Below are some examples, based on measurements of the Arial font:

```
font-size    baseline height
   10           7
   11           8
   12           9
   14           10
```

In theory, for CSS, pt is a rough approximation of the baseline height in px. For instance, a font-size:9pt has a baseline height of 9px, which corresponds to font-size:12px. In practice, I've sometimes found that pt is larger than the baseline height by 0.5 to 1.0 px.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/bJM8W/) showing a side-by-side comparison of capital H's in px and pt.

In most PSDs I've seen, a font specified as 12pt is in fact 12px. But this may vary. When in doubt, measure the baseline height of the text and convert backwards from that to a font-size in px. For instance, if a capital H has a height of 9px, then the font-size is 12px. Sometimes antialiasing in a PSD makes it difficult to accurately measure the baseline height.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for this great, in-depth answer.

Comment: This explanation may be good for practical cases with most fonts, but remember that in theory things are very different. You may encounter fonts where those proportions differ considerably. Font designers may add as much whitespace as they want.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868627/photoshop-pt-size-conversion-to-web) from a similar question about font size in Photoshop and CSS.

While [here](http://www.sherriwyche.com/tools/fontconversion.html) You can find a nice conversione table: you can notice that PT in Photoshop are equivalent to PX in CSS.. i think you shouldn't use PT in both.

Finally, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)) you can read something about the history of PT in typography (yes, you are right about 1pt = 1/72 inch) :)

Answer (score 2):

It's usually better practice to measure font in pixels in CSS. Like the question you asked pt size is pretty arbitrary and varies upon the developers own definitions.

Answer (score 2):

1. In [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/) (the current spec), pt is unambiguously 1/72 of an inch. The reality is different, though, and this is reflected in the [CSS3 Values and Units draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/), section 5. It describes two setups, using different “anchor units”. If the pixel is the anchor unit, an inch (`in` as CSS unit) need not be an inch (the physical unit, 2.54 mm), and hence the meaning of `p` may vary as well. This is one reason why `pt` in CSS need not match `pt` in some software.
2. The font size is a basic property of a font. Any relationships between it and dimensions of characters are up to the font designer, but font design is of course not arbitrary. The CSS 2.1 spec puts this rather vaguely, but the formulation is still useful (against many common misconceptions): “The font size corresponds to the em square, a concept used in typography. Note that certain glyphs may bleed outside their em squares.” (And on the other hand, most glyphs use just a small part of the em square.)

Answer (score 1):

"pt" in fonts is only for print CSS. 
Here is a link which explains all differences between types of sizes
http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/

Answer (score 1):

You can go straight to the official W3C documentation on CSS for specifics of the [font-size](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-size-props) property.

And to your question about the meaning of `pt` *in CSS*, again the [official documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#length-units) shows that yes, it is 1/72 of an inch.

Remember that in different applications you can zoom your screen, so think about these values more for printed, rather than screen, media.

Comment: So the computed value of "absolute length" means that font size determines the length of letters?

Answer (score 0):

1)

In **print** css, a pt is exactly 1/72 of an inch.

In **screen**
    css everything is defined in terms of pixels, and a pt is defined as
    1 1/3 pixel. But how large this is in physical measurements like inch
    depend on screen DPI and vary greatly between devices. For this
    reason, pt (and other physical measurements like in, cm etc.) is not
    that useful in screen css.

2)

Font-size refers the the height of the "em-box" - a bit
    simplified this is the rectangle which can contain all letters in
    the font including ascenders and descenders. Individual letters will of course 
    often take up less space than the whole em-box. For example a
    lower-case x will have space above and below, while a lower-case j
    might fill the whole height of the em-box.

Font-size therefore indicates how much vertical space is required by a line of text, but the dimensions of individual letters and glyphs will vary relative to others depending on the letter and the design of the font in use.

Furthermore some fonts may have letters which extend ("bleed") even outside the em box, which is also a stylistic choice by the designers of the font. E.g. the letter "Å" will often bleed above the em-box.