# Why does the <button> tag treat em differently from how a <div> does?

Tags: css, font-size

I've noticed that <button> tags seem to be scaling em units from something other than the font-size. <div> tags aren't exhibiting this same behaviour.
This happens across the latest versions of chrome, firefox & ie.

They are both styled like this:

```
button, div {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3em;
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TyCbd/) for an example.

If I size a div and a button both with a width of 3rem and height of 3em, I would expect them to be square, unless there is a font-size style affecting one of them, or an ancestor. The only font-size is on the <body> tag, but what happens is that the div is square, but the button has a smaller height than its width.

If I inspect the button in chrome, it says that it inherits the 1em font-size from the <body> tag, and yet the problem is fixed when I set its font size to 1em explictly (see fiddle).

Can anyone explain to me what's happening here? It feels like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your HTML button was not inheriting font size from `<body>`. I believe many form elements behave this way (at least in some browsers), though I have no documentation.

I had success by adding:

```
button {
    font-size:inherit;
}
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TyCbd/1/)

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Because the chrome inspector indicated that it _was_ inheriting that font size, I was thrown by this.

Comment: Yeah, it's funky. A [bug report was marked as invalid](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=650584) because this is (apparently) according to spec. But I can't find any reference to official documentation. Maybe someone else can?...

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is that browsers apply a default browser style sheet that causes reduced font size to be used for `button` elements. This is not described in specifications, and the amount of reduction may vary by browser. You can see the same thing happening for `input` elements like `<input type="text">` by default: the font size is smaller than in the surrounding text (though this may be difficult to see if different font faces are used, which is a common default).

Developer Tools in browsers aren’t perfect. For example, Chrome indeed shows `font-size` of a `button` element as inherited—but is also shows the computed size as smaller. The explanation is that the browser’s default style sheet has `font: -webkit-small-control` for `button`, and this is the setting that really matters here. The information about inheritance is simply incorrect.

When you set `font-size: 1em` (or, equivalently, `font-size: 100%`) on the `button` element, you override the default setting. This is somewhat better than setting `font-size: inherit`, which has slightly less widespread browser support.