# Center Align a Child Div with Display Inline-Block and set float Left

Tags: css, alignment, center

I have a working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/V3Suq/29/

**Question**

How to make child align to left, for example like this screenshot: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9YCj.png)

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    background: #f00;
    height: 210px;
   text-align: center;
}

.child {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `text-align: left;` with `parent` class and update width from `%` to `px` like this `width: 500px;` and set `padding-left` to some `px`, so your updated `parent`class is look like

```
.parent {
    width: 500px;
    background: #f00;
    height: 210px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left:50px;
}
```

FIDDLE is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/V3Suq/45/)

Comment: Hi @usman, thanks for your reply...but if I set text align to left the child div will not centered.

Comment: Yes that's better, but how if we don't know the left padding of childs or the parent width?

Comment: @Luxor means you want to say how much we add `px` left padding of child??and how much `px` the parent width should??

Comment: I mean, we want the width of parent in %, so it will responsive.

Comment: if you set it to `100%` means you allow your `div` to increase it width dynamically according to your div content. you may better understand with this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385829/what-is-the-difference-between-px-em-and-ex

Comment: you can set the parent width in your FIDDLE to 100% and resize the window so the child position not in center anymore. :(

Comment: Maybe we need to use jQuery to make it. Suggestion?

Comment: you can use JQuery, but JQuery is not a solution, in the end from JQuery you will be changing CSS, and as far as the `width` of parent, you have to change it to some `px` other wise you have to alter your HTML to achieve what you need