# Is it possible to open the site zoomed in based on resolution of user's monitor?

Tags: javascript, html, resolution

I have this site which was developed few years back. At that time it was developed keeping 1024x768 resolution in mind. Now a days people use much higher resolution.

I was thinking if it is possible to open the site zoomed in automatically if the resolution of user's monitor is set considerably higher than 1024x768?

Right now if I look my site on my macbook it looks like following:
[image]

I would like it to be opened up like following:

[image]

I hope I have explained the question correctly.

Comment: edited the tags, the question had nothing to do with php alone.

Comment: Accept rate means you have to accept the answers that helped you. Regarding your question, you mean zoom like when pressing `CTRL`+`+` or changing zoom level of IE?

Answer (score 0):

My browser settings are my own! It's none of the webeveloper's business to change anything in that area!

What you may be looking for however, are flexible layouts. (But that doesn't work well when you integrate pictures, as with zooming, they tend to get pixelated...)

### Update

If you want to have a flexible layout that scales well and easily (also through scripting), you can [consider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609517/why-em-instead-of-px) [using](http://jontangerine.com/log/2007/09/the-incredible-em-and-elastic-layouts-with-css) [the](http://clagnut.com/blog/348/) *[em](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss/)* [unit](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_units.asp).

To have only a layout adjust to the screen width for instnace, you can also use percentage values.

Comment: I am not asking to change the settings of whole browser, can't we change settings for my site alone? It's like if I change zoom settings of one tab, it does not affect all the tabs.

Comment: Yes.. I was being a little too... what is the word, exaggerating? Well... there is always the em unit.