# What is the difference between declaring px vs percentage on the body of a website?

Tags: html, css, reset

We currently have a reset that says, body { font-size: 75%; } which translates to 12px if the standard size is 16px.  I'm trying to figure out why wouldn't I just say body { font-size: 12px; } THanks!~

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714543/font-size62-5-vs-font-size10px

Comment: There was a sound technical reason to prefer percentages in IE6. Hopefully, those days are history.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely preference. You can read about all the benefits and disadvantages here > [CSS Font-Size: em vs. px vs. pt vs. percent](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/). (first link in google search)

> In theory, the em unit is the new and upcoming standard for font sizes
>   on the web, but in practice, the percent unit seems to provide a more
>   consistent and accessible display for users. When client settings have
>   changed, percent text scales at a reasonable rate, allowing designers
>   to preserve readability, accessibility, and visual design.

also, check out [this](http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/)

Comment: pt is for print. Do not use pt for the web. http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html#units

Comment: Thanks for the info! Will take note of that for my future projects!