# why font size 62.5% for body tag not working?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to implement the font-size: 62.5% for the body tag:

```
body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

I have it in my _reset.scss file but for some reason, it doesn't work. I have two screenshots from the Chrome DevTools.

Here's the GitHub link for my project:
https://github.com/MajesticBay/nearballard_v2

Here's the link for the live version:
https://nearballardv2.netlify.app/

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check your code. In the _reset.scss you have called body tag at two places and called the same font-size fucntion at two places with two sizes.

```
body {
    //1rem = 10px 10px/16px = 62.5%
    font-size: 62.5%;
    //will increase or reduce the font-size based on the screen size in the future
}
```

You called it here with font-size and

```
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

You also called it here.

Try correcting it and if it stills get error. Lets try finding another.

Comment: Please dont forget to upvote for my reputation

Comment: I saw that before but it's not the case. I commented it out but it's still not working.

Comment: Is the above given link is your website? If so, I don't think there is a problem. I have visited it and it is perfect

Comment: yes, that's the link. it's 32px but it's supposed to be 20px.

Answer (score 1):

I re-observed your code to get the font correct. You want to change the font-size from 32px to 20px, right?.. Ok, here's what to do. You can select the class of the element in the style sheet. In this case it is in component.css. In there change the font-size of heading-primary from 2rem to 1.25rem. It will change the size of 'Location' from 32px to 20px..

Change the font-size from this

```
.heading-primary {
    font-family: "Monument Extended";
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 150%;
    color: var(--color-secondary);
}
```

to this

```
.heading-primary {
    font-family: "Monument Extended";
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 150%;
    color: var(--color-secondary);
}
```

[image: Size rechanged]

If this is not your problem..don't hesitate to say

Comment: Thank you, @Rockzy for taking your time, I really appreciate it. I do agree that this is the solution, it's just that I'm trying to implement the technique, that I've used before. Here's the stackoverflow question with it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988445/css-62-5-why-do-developers-use-it. And here's the example of the website where I implemented it, but I just can't understand what I did different this time: https://github.com/awesome-store/front-end