# How does using 'em' help me in css?

Tags: font-size

I've heard that using 'em' for font size is recommended. I've tried it, but I really don't see any advantage of it. Actually, all of my co-workers were confused.

I've read few articles over the internet about %, em, and px. All of them suggested em, but I really don't understand it. Yes, I can change all the font size at once by using em...is that it?

I've tried several smartphones and all of them displayed 'px' without a problem...

Someone please guide me!

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609517/why-em-instead-of-px

Comment: @poczciwy // ha...thank you! Should I close this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font unit `em` allows you to display font size ( as well as other element's size , e.g. images ) based on browser's configuration.

You can still use `px` as font unit, but 14px browser on mobile is different than 14px on desktop browser.

Comment: Actually it allows you to set *any* size based on browser font settings, allowing you to scale images and whatever else you want. It really helps people with poor eyesight that choose larger text in their browser if you use em as opposed to px.