# best practices when using em instead of px

Tags: html, css

I'm starting a new project and considering to use em.

What are the best practices to be followed when using em instead of px (to create a scalable layout).

I would also welcome any pitfalls with this approach and possible solutions to it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why em instead of px?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609517/why-em-instead-of-px)

Comment: I searched for this on google, found this questions, and *gasp* its closed. Too bad SO is so hostile towards useful questions. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a great article on Fluid Grids that can help get you started:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/

Answer (score 1):

The best trick I know is to set the `body` text size to `62.5%`. This way any `em` value you use will have a direct correlation to `px` sizes. Eg `1.2em` = `12px`

This is of course assuming the element you are setting the `em` size on does not have any parents which have already had their size set, in which case you will need to do some maths to work out the relative size.

Comment: Not exactly a panacea, but a better approach would be to set `body` text size to `10px`. http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/1230/the-problem-with-bodyfont-size62.5-and-ems/p1

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out a book called "Responsive Web Design". It has some great best practices when it comes to using EMs and %s for layout, type, and images:  http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design