# CSS em assistance needed

Tags: html, css

I am currently designing a web page with em units.  I guess I don't understand it as well as I thought I did because a problem has occurred while I tried to align two separate span tags with margin-left.  They were placed in the upper-left corner of my header.  They were positioned on top of one another using display:block.  When I used margin-right to align both the span tags, the larger span and the smaller tag didn't align correctly.  I used the same number for margin-right, but they were still messed up.

- Is this because I'm using em's?
- How can I fix this?

I will paste the code I'm using below so you'll get a sense of what I'm working with.  Hopefully I've explained this well enough.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="header1">
      <span class="title">Title goes here</span>
      <span class="subtitle">This is the subtitle</span>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    color: #333;
    font-family: 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 62.5%; /* 10px */
    line-height: 1.28;
}
.main1 {
  width: 96em;
  /* horizontally center the website layout */
  margin: 0 auto; margin-top: .8em;
  text-Align: left; /* override body {text-align:center} */
}
div.header1 {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 9em;
  background: #ff0000;
  color: #fff;
}
.title {
  font: small-caps 700 3.7em "Goudy Old Style", Garamond, "Big Caslon", "Times New Roman", serif;
}
.subtitle {
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

Comment: You say that you "positioned on top of one another using display:block" but all this does is convert the inline element to a block level element. You need to use `position: absolute;` to place them on top of one another. Do this, test what you have and reply back you continue to have issues.

Comment: It would make more sense if you use `<hgroup>` and `<h2>Title</h2><h3>Subtitle</h3>`

Comment: Also, where's the `display: block` part? Where's the `margin-left:` part? They're missing from your code!

Answer (score 2):

The description of the problem is very confusing and does not explain what you want to achieve and what is your best attempt at that. You refer to left *and* right margin, but neither of them is set in your code for the elements discussed. You refer to setting `display: block`, but there is no such setting.

I will assume that you want the main title to appear (in the xy plane) above the subtitle. For this you need to set `display: block` or, better, use `div` markup instead of `span` or, best, use adequate heading markup such as `h1` and `h2` with due consideration of their default effects on vertical margins and font weight (i.e., overriding them in CSS if needed). And I assume that you wanted them left-aligned the same amount.

It seems that you did not take into account the relativity of the `em` unit. By definition, it equals the font size of the element (except in `font-size`, where it equals the font size of the parent element).

I suspect that you tried setting the left margin of both `span` elements using the same value such as `1em`. But it does not mean the same for both elements, since their `em` sizes differ. If you wanted to set the their left margins to, say, the font size of the first element, you would set

```
.title { margin-left: 1em; }
.subtitle { margin-left: 2.6429em; }
```

The number `2.6429` is the ratio of the font sizes, calculated from 3.7/1.4.

It would be easier to just set a left margin on the enclosing `div` element. Its font size equals the font size of the `body` element, so if you wanted to set it to the font size of the main heading, you would use

```
div.header1 { margin-left: 3.7em; }
```

Answer (score 0):

check the bellow link I hope this will help for you

http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: I've seen the website before, but I still don't understand why my numbers are acting up.

Comment: [Link only answers are discouraged!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) Please write a full answer, instead of just providing a link.

Answer (score 0):

**px:** pixels (a dot on the computer screen)

**em:** 1em is equal to the current font size. 2em means 2 times the size of the current font. E.g., if an element is displayed with a font of 12 pt, then '2em' is 24 pt. The 'em' is a very useful unit in CSS, since it can adapt automatically to the font that the reader uses.

[see the reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609517/why-em-instead-of-px)

So, you can use `px` instead `em`, its good practice.

Hope it will helps you. Thanks. !!