# Why does MS recommend using points over pixels for win 8 apps?

Tags: css, windows-8, font-size

In the ms style guidelines for win 8 development they specify the font sizes in points over ems or pixels.

Anyone know the reason for this?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700394.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why em instead of px?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609517/why-em-instead-of-px)

Comment: @sachleen , not a duplicate. OP is asking why Microsoft suggest using **pt** instead of **em** or **px**

Comment: It is easy to guess that they don't want users with different screen resolutions to see texts in different sizes.

Comment: Not a duplicate...that question is tagged CSS and (while most of it is *probably* generic/relevant) this is talking specifically about Windows 8 development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is, Microsoft made the relationship between **pt** and **px** broken in older browsers (such as Internet Explorer 7). Therefore, the whole company's products stick to **pt**, instead of **px** or **em**. Also, there are many reasons associated, such as copyright and branding.

Detailed Explanation: [Point Size and the Em Square: Not What People Think](http://www.thomasphinney.com/2011/03/point-size/)

Comment: Yup sounds like Microsoft alright - opposite of everyone else's direction, even when the majority found a great solution.