# When container width is defined in em unit in responsive friendly design?

Tags: css

I am learning about Relative Unit of measurement for responsive design. But i am little bit confused seeing many designers are using em unit in defining their container width. I have also seen while defining media queries,the breaking point is defined in em. what is benefit of using em in layout. I will be thankful to you who can show me real life benefit of em in using in layout. I used em in layout of my design. i was expecting that em will behave like percentage while squeezing browser window but it behaved like pixel. so, why does designers prefer em instead of px ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why em instead of px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609517/why-em-instead-of-px)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been already raised in stack overflow.

Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609517/why-em-instead-of-px)  for it.