# Why are the 2 divs not starting at the same position

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/y8LhR/1/

```
<div class="narrow heading">Heading</div>
<div class="narrow">Description goes here</div>


.narrow{
    margin-left:5em;
    margin-right:5em; 
}
.heading{
    font-size:36px;
}
```

Why is increasing the font of heading moving it farther away from left?

If I replace 12 em by 165 px in CSS the desired effect is achieved. But then the site will not appear as wanted with different window sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the `left-margin:5em;` 5em is 5 times the font-size so as the font-size on the `.heading` is bigger, the `left-margin` is bigger.

more information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

**EDIT**

If you want a responsive margin, you need to use percentage

Answer (score 1):

An `em` is a multiple of the element's current font size.  Since `.heading` has a bigger font, it's going to have more of a margin.

If you don't want the margin to vary with font size, try using `px` (pixels) or possibly `rem` (multiples of the root element's font) instead.

Answer (score 1):

> em is not an absolute unit - it is a unit that is relative to the currently chosen font size.

your margin is changing based on the font size, that's why `heading` margin is different.

You can find here (IMHO) some very good info: [Why EM instead of PX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609517/why-em-instead-of-px)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Adobe Glossary](https://www.adobe.com/type/topics/glossary.html#em)

> Em is traditionally defined as the width of the uppercase M in the current face and point size. It is more properly defined as simply the current point size. For example, in 12-point type, em is a distance of 12 points.

You will see that if you change `em` with an absolute measure like `px`, you'll achieve the result.