# HTML Character - Invisible space

Tags: html, css, hidden, space

I have a website called Dalton**Empire**.

When a user copies "DaltonEmpire" I would like "Dalton Empire" to be added to their clipboard.

I only came to one solution; use a space, but make the `letter-spacing` `-18px`.
Isn't there a neater solution, such as a HTML character for this?

My example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4BbLU/) and code:

```css
span.nospace {
  letter-spacing: -18px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Dalton<b>Empire</b></li>
  <li>Dalton&zwnj;<b>Empire</b></li>
  <li>Dalton&zwj;<b>Empire</b></li>
  <li>Dalton&#8203;<b>Empire</b></li>
  <li>Dalton<span class="nospace"> </span><b>Empire</b> <i>The only one that works</i>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `word-spacing` for this. However to make a more dynamic property you want to use the `em` unit. This way the unit is based on the font-size, so actually supports all the font families *and* font sizes:

```
ol li
{
    word-spacing: -.2em;
}
```

> em is not an absolute unit - it is a unit that is relative to the
> currently chosen font size.

source: [Why em instead of px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609517/why-em-instead-of-px)

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4BbLU/3/)

Comment: Thanks! This indeed works and [is not dependant on the font size](http://jsfiddle.net/4BbLU/4/)! +1 for the explanation of `em`, I didn't know this!

Comment: @Isaiah - Note that this answer is also dependent on the ratio of the width of the space character to the font-size. For example, you would need about `-0.5em` for `Courier New` on Windows.

Comment: curiously, when i tried this on a long list of labels, i got the occasional 1px misalignment, noticable because of the border around the label.

Answer (score 20):

Here is some interesting and related info. It doesn't solve your problem, but it may help people who are searching for a way to create an optional line-break, like I was. The Zero-Width Space `&#8203;` and `<wbr>` element are two possible options.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#wbr
- http://graphemica.com/search?q=space

Comment: Should be chosen answer, never knew about <wbr> !

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what I was looking for to solve an unnatural line break issue.

Answer (score 15):

Are you looking something like this:

HTML space: `&nbsp;` ?

Comment: Thank you but no. I want an invisible space, only visible when copying.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missunderstood :)

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `font-size: 0;` [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4BbLU/1/)

```
span.nospace {
        font-size: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This still requires an ugly span, but this'd work everywhere and isn't dependant on the actual font-size (logically). However, there's one better solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Looks neat enough to me:

```
ol li{
    word-spacing: -4px; /* just enter an appropriate amount here */
}
```

You can now remove the nospace span.

Comment: This works, only (as my original solution) this would [depend on the font size](http://jsfiddle.net/4BbLU/2/), and I'd have to adjust it manually. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

you can give `margin-left` or `Font-size` CSS property

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/8Q54P/1/)

```
span.nospace {

    margin-left: -4px; /* or font-size:0px */
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but same for you as I said to @Av Avt. This would depend on the font size, not ideal, Thanks anyway!