# Which unit should be used in web design

Tags: css

I am trying to design new website but I have some problems. I am using 13inch laptop when I look at the site in my computers browser everything is fine but when I look at the bigger screen div's are shown smaller etc. Which units should I use for div's width, height and the margins ? I have already try px em and know I have made it something like this.

```
.tBackground{
        margin-left:10%;
        margin-top: -200px;
        margin-bottom:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        height: 30%;
        width: 110%;
        background: rgba(80, 78, 78, 0.75);
        overflow:auto;

}
```

with this css it is normal at bigger screen but in my 13inch laptop it is very big it doesn't fit the screen

Comment: Maybe `%` but for each `width, height and margins (h/v)` it could be different and may cause trouble.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no answer to this question. There is no "right" way. The problem you face is what each and every css author faces each and every day.

Comment: This question is way, way too broad. You need to investigate responsive web design. It allows you to optimize designs based on screen resolution.

Answer (score 1):

There's not simply *one* unit to be used in web design.  The reason that they're all there is for variation.  It entirely depends on what you want:

**px** - *Does not scale down for mobile devices*

**em** - *Does scale down for mobile devices*

**percent** - *Takes up a set amount of the screen*

It depends entirely on what is trying to be accomplished.  However, these are just basic differences.  If you would like to read more about them, you can visit [this website](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/) (which also includes pt).

Also, you can read the answers to this StackOverflow question: [Why em instead of px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609517/why-em-instead-of-px)