# Speed test between size units: rem, em and px

Tags: css, performance, paint, font-size

Is there any evidence of a particular sizing unit taking longer to process? For instance, if you were to use `rem` to size your entire site would it take longer to calculate/paint the page than if everything were given a specific `px` value?

Is there any benefit to `max-width: 16rem` over `max-width: 250px`?

I'm under the impression that `rem` takes longer since it has to revert back to the root and calculate while `em` is like a steady stream of processing, and `px` would be the fastest because there's nothing to calculate.

Please let me know if anyone has any evidence of which method is faster

Comment: the differences would be absolutely ngligable. Why care? There are many more pressing issues on CPU, GPU, browser / server OS, RAM, bandwidth and general website usage.

Comment: Create a heavy page that uses `rem / %` and one that uses exclusively `px`. Use Chrome's inspector. I would bet that the computing *painting* process could be faster for px :)

Comment: Thanks @RokoC.Buljan, I've tried that but got inconsistent results. Guess it wasn't heavy enough or elements not nested deep enough.

Comment: @TimMcKay it's a totally awesome question and to be honest I never had a coffee with this Q in mind... But from a **common sense**, I believe that using responsive units might cost some more computation, pixel, subpixel etc...  I'll try to look deeper into it as time avails.

Comment: @Martin I've made sites that used `rem` pretty heavily and it slowed down the css animations created which lead me to the assumption that `rem` takes longer to process.

Comment: I must conceed that css-animations specifically are much heavier users of processor power than general `font-size` *etc* static rules.

Comment: @TimMcKay thank you, but I don't think you should mark me as the correct answer, at least, not yet, I've stated that I think there's little value in what you're seeking and I have given you some links to further reading, I have not (in my view) answered your question. Perhaps wait a day or two for other responses? But thanks anyhow :D

Answer (score 5):

> **Edit:** I started off pretty much dismissing this discussion as, well,
>   polishing the roof of a truck, but I had not considered css-animations
>   which are quite heavy pocessor users and with CSS not being a
>   graphically optimized process (-very inefficient) then I think
>   there is a *slightly* higher warrent for such a question, if a website
>   has a large number of css-animations.

Quote from question:

> I'm under the impression that `rem` takes longer since it has to revert back to the root and calculate while `em` is like a steady stream of processing, and px would be the fastest because there's nothing to calculate.

No. Rem simply takes a factor of the `root em value`, rather than the `parent em value`. *(As the root doesn't change I would hope that the structure processing of CSS doesn't need to keep calling it and can instead simply regain it from memory)*.

`rem` Is the way we should be writing CSS in 2016. It beats lights out of `em` beyond having one or two parent elements effecting the `em` value, for instance [from the pont of view of working out as a developer what `1.2em of 1.4 em of 1.2 em of 14px` is, why not just have `1.2 of 14px` as `1.2rem`].

As for `px`, that is not a straight-to-screen result either as with many modern display devices, the pixel is not a pixel, [this may be an interesting topic for you to read](http://alistapart.com/article/a-pixel-identity-crisis).

If you care about the speed of processing `rem` against `px` then I personally feel you're in effect trying to get better fuel efficiency from your truck by polishing the roof so that air resistence is reduced, your work may have a *tiny* impact but there are other far larger consumers of GPU,CPU ram and operating power, and many more of them.

You may also like to read this: [How a CSS pixel size is calculated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382331/how-a-css-pixel-size-is-calculated)

And because I want to entertain you, you may like to know that [you can now generate full 3D computer game levels developed entirely through CSS](http://keithclark.co.uk/labs/css-fps/). This was made in 2013! *I still find it increadible!!*

In this game the developer used `px` throughout. You could perhaps take his code and apply `em` and/or `rem` and the heaviness of the page will display if it is indeed notably faster.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, this helps a lot. Particularly like your fuel efficiency analogy. haha. What are your thoughts on [Chris Coyier's modular font-sizing](https://css-tricks.com/rems-ems/)? Your `root em value` explanation clears things up quite a bit. Thanks for the pixel size calculation link. Feel like that'll be pretty interesting.

I guess it's more about writing better css and wondering at what size of a page would this have an impact, but my comment about css animations may be more about how css transitions/animations are processed than calculating rems.

Thanks again

Comment: @TimMcKay The game by Keith Clark is increadible. I really suggest checking it out. And realise that what you're viewing is the same - or simpler- technology than StackOverflow is running with!

Comment: @TimMcKay re: your link of Chris Coyier, I think you should *only* use `em` for fonts if you know the parent size (in px) and you know exactly what *percentage of that size you want*. font-size is one of the areas `rem` comes into its own, in my view. As for his idea I accept them as ideas but to be honest I would far easier just adjust sizes/scales in (already  prepared) media queries that are sitting in the CSS anyway for mobile compatibility.