# How can I make sure text never is falling of the screen

Tags: jquery, css

I have a little question about dealing with font size and window width. Sometimes my headers are just one long word and with smaller devices this word is falling of the screen so you only see a small part of the word.

How can I make sure that you always see the full word on every screen?

I have tried several css solutions but than the word breaks and continues on the next rule.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using the unit `vw` - viewport width.

Comment: what do you mean falling of the screen? do you mean text goes to the next line ?

Comment: I think you can use this property: word-wrap: break-word;

Comment: yes but wat I actually want is that the headers are always on the same line and that the font size depends on the width of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want a flexible solution, and already use jQuery for other reasons, you can easily use the [jQuery-quickfit](http://chunksnbits.github.io/jquery-quickfit/) plugin that does exactly this.

Comment: Thanks! This looks very easy and safe for every scenario. I think this is the solution I'm going to use.

Answer (score 3):

If you want that font-size depends on the width of the screen then you can just easily do it through media queries.

See demo.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 0.68em;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 0.87em;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>How can I make sure text never is falling of the screen This is a long header</h1>
```

You can also go here for more info about different media device screen size

See [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: Thanks so much! Very interesting, I did not expect a css solution. What does 'em' actually mean?

Comment: em means the width of a capital `M` character, you could change the size in px / pt or other units for the same effect

Comment: [why use em instead of px when defining styles in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609517/why-em-instead-of-px)

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries and adapt the text size to different screen sizes.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer but I "don't know" the length of the headers so it has to be variable so it can never happen that the text is falling of the screen.