# Text Stacking Over Itself

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website from a template, and for some reason the text in the lower left corner stacks on itself when I reduce the window size. I am by no means an expert in HTML/CSS but I can't seem to figure out why exactly it is doing this. I've tried messing with the div properties and the z-index. It looks like this

[image: The problem]

My HTML code:

```
<!-- Site Logo -->
    <div id="logo">salem music</div>
```

CSS:

```
#logo {
font-family: 'Coustard', serif;
font-size: 49px;
bottom:40px;
height:auto;
left:40px;
position:absolute;
width:20%;
z-index:1000;
color: #fff;
}
```

I'd like it to look like

[image: This]

Comment: The width of that element becomes to narrow to show both words without wrapping to the next line (`width:20%`). What would you like to happen instead? (e.g. words overflow the container instead of wrapping)

Comment: If the window is too small I'd like all that text to stay static, if possible. Even when the window is relatively large it will stack on itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `width` is set to `20%`. If you decrease the window width, then eventually the `#logo` element will get too small in width and will cause the text to wrap.

Consider setting a larger `width` value.

```css
.logo {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 10px;
}
.logo1 {
  width: 5%;
}
.logo2 {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo logo1">This width is too small and will wrap</div>
<div class="logo logo2">This width is better and won't wrap</div>
```

---

Or, if you want to keep it that width, and want to allow text to overflow out of the `<div>`, you can use `white-space: nowrap`. However, I wouldn't recommend this, as it would probably overlap the links next to it.

```css
.logo {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 10px;
}
.logo1 {
  width: 5%;
}
.logo2 {
  width: 5%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo logo1">This width is too small and will wrap</div>
<div class="logo logo2">This will not wrap even though it is too small</div>
```

---

@Bálint made a good point in the comments as well: when possible, use the `em` unit for measurements instead of percentages. [`em`s are based on font size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/609561/2397327), rather than window size. Therefore, changing the window wouldn't affect it, but changing the font size would (in a desirable way).

Comment: @Bálint I'm using percentages to keep consistent with the OP's CSS. But yes, I will edit that in.

Comment: I know, I added as a side note for the OP

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, adjusting the width made it so that the text stayed in place until the window squished it.

Comment: I'm still learning and wasn't exactly sure what the width property did, so I'll mess around with that and use em's.