# Good practice to write CSS Media Queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I am fairly new to CSS Media queries. I am actually trying to adjust left margin for a button **('Add+' button as shown in the attached image)** for different screen widths. I am trying to do this:

```
 @media only screen  and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 350px)
    {
        .button_orange_extended
        {
            margin-left:0px;
        }
    }   /*Media query for one specific screen width*/



  @media only screen  and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 400px)
    {
        .button_orange_extended
        {

            margin-left:30px;
        }
    } /*Another Media query for  specific screen width*/



  @media only screen  and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 450px)
    {
        .button_orange_extended
        {

            margin-left:80px;
        }
    }
```

By this means, i got to write this code around 10-12 times and adjust margin accordingly. Considering that i need to adjust margins not only for mobiles but for other devices like tablets. So, is there an short alternative approach? (Below is the image).

[image]

Comment: You're missing 10px between first and second queries... once you have one min width the rest only need `max-width` because by default, the `min-width` is covered by the previous `max-width` - also, if you have lots of these, maybe look at using % for `margin-left` that will cover a lot of devices

Comment: @DarrenSweeney But still for every specific screen width, i got to write a seperate media query. In this way, i will write around 12-15 media queries which is not a good practice i think.

Comment: Without seeing your design it's hard to answer and suggest a better way unfortunately

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I have edited my answer. Check now!

Comment: Why don't you float the button right then use `right-margin` then it's the same on every device - using `margin-left` as you are is dangerous and not really maintainable

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `px`, you can use `em`. `em`s are relative to the current font size, whereas `px` is an absolute unit of measurement. So if you used `em` on all your elements, you could just change the `body`'s `font-size`. This way, you won't have to set the size of every element per every different screen width, you'll only have to change the font size. I've used http://pxtoem.com/ for converting from `px` to `em`, I'd recommend it for beginners. Also, a very good post describing why you should use `em` instead of `px`: [Why em instead of px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609517/why-em-instead-of-px/609561#609561)

Comment: Thankyou! But I'm not concerned with font size. I need to adjust margin for the button. It has nothing to do with 'em'

Comment: Oh, okay. But `em` is very useful in responsive design (just a tip!) So the answer is no, there is no shorter way to do it. But I did notice you used `0px` for the first media query. It can be shortened down to just `0`. That's the most it can be shortened (as far as I know).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is the opposite of a responsive approach in the sense that you seem to target specific device screen sizes and, as you say, you will have to write the same media query 10-12 times for a single class doing so. Also, you seem to try and position your element in a certain way by pushing it a number of pixels further to the right as you scale up. That wont work. The best approach is to use a framework of your own design or bootstrap to create a grid where it is easier to manage positioning elements. I never have to use more than four media query rules, and then put all the needed exceptions for classes, id;s etc inside them. Set a default value for your classes, starting with mobile. That way, you need no media query rule for the smallest screen sizes ( and very few rules in total );

```
.button_orange_extended {
// other additional rules if any
// you need no margin rule for left-margin here since it is set to 0 anyway
}
// Then you can set you media query exceptions to anything, example;
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
        .button_orange_extended {

        }
    }
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
        .button_orange_extended {

        }
    }
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
        .button_orange_extended {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need media queries for this. You can use percent on *margin-left*. For example

```
margin-left: 80%
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ld6025vf/