# How does a user benefit from "em" measurements instead of "px"?

Tags: html, css, font-size

I've read quite a bit about the "em" measurement for "font-size" and I've noticed that some say that especially disabled users benefit from "em" because they can adjust the size of font.

I'm new to CSS & HTML and I do not understand how this really works.
As I understand I can always - as a user - enlarge the viewing size in my browser. Doesn't this also work when I use "px" all the time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why em instead of px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609517/why-em-instead-of-px)

Comment: "Doesn't this also work when I use "px" all the time?" Yes, but it wasn't true in the past.

Comment: Does that mean there is no difference between "px" and "em" today and the size adjusts itself when the user switched the size in browser??

Answer (score 1):

`Em` represents a page's default size, so for example, `1em` might be `12px`, but for larger screens may be something else, perhaps `16px`. `2em` would be twice that size of `1em`.

The takeaway is `em` scales with the screen resolution and is a good choice for responsive design.

`Px` on the other hand is a specific, fixed sizing guide, where a pixel is one square on a screen. So `12px` on one screen may look small on a larger screen.

I recommend using em for most purposes unless there's a good reason you need a specific pixel size.

Comment: Is rem same as em ?

Comment: @Kal em is relative to parent, so each element should consider its parent and rem is relative to root, so all the element will have the same reference

Comment: So rem might be better for consistency across all objects right ? All h1s will be same size no matter what their parent size is ?

Comment: @curtis So I don't have to set a parent in "px" first? I would just say the heading is 1em and the paragraphs below are 0.9em? And the screen resolution of the user decides how much "px" 1em, or 0.9em is, right?

Comment: @Hip Right. Here's a site that explains how to use rem and em.

https://j.eremy.net/confused-about-rem-and-em/

Comment: @CurtisWhite Can you tell me if I'm right assuming that when I have two "div"-containers, and the first "font-size" would be 10px for 1em(because of the resolution of the device) - the child container would calculate upwards from this 10px to 1.2em(12px) and not from 16px, which is usually the default size? So with **em** the resolution adjusts itself without me having to first say 10px = 1em, and so on?`<div style="font-size=1em">Example<div style="font-size=1.2em">Example2</div></div>`

Comment: Sounds about right. I haven't used it like that in a while though. It's best to look up examples to see how it behaves, or test it on your own website