# Box-Shadow color by image

Tags: html, css

I would like to make images with an iOS shadow like this (https://codepen.io/mathias-madsen-stav/pen/ampKpO?editors=1100), automatically generated from the colors of the image. I am not interested in the hover effect, but only in the shadow. However, I would like the box to be responsive and to fit the image size, without specifying an exact size in px.

The main problem is to modify this part of the code:

```
width: ...px;
height: ...px;
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: It might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609517/why-em-instead-of-px

Comment: @AmritDumre yeah I know, but I would like to mantain image proportions on multiple images with different proportions. Moreover, I would like the box 100% width